# Error returned with array_count_values after rounding and multiplying

Tags: php

I would like to be able to use array_count_values in the following way:

```
$roundedans = 10 * round($groupdiff, 1);
$diffarray[] = $roundedans;

print_r(array_count_values($diffarray));
```

The first two lines are part of a while loop that inserts $roundedans into the array and array_count_values is called outside of the loop.

When I try to run the code I get this error:

```
Warning: array_count_values() [function.array-count-values]: Can only count STRING and INTEGER values! in...
```

This is even though I've converted all of the values to an integer by multiplying by 10.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the output from just print_r:

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 15 [2] => 8 [3] => 13 [4] => -60 [5] => 1 [6] => -61 [7] => 7 [8] => 49 [9] => 26 [10] => -3 [11] => -66 [12] => 20 [13] => 10 [14] => 6 [15] => -94 [16] => -1 [17] => -6 [18] => -19 [19] => -1 [20] => 48 [21] => -4 [22] => 45 [23] => 21 [24] => -11 [25] => 19 [26] => 1 [27] => -10 [28] => 4 [29] => -14 [30] => 26 [31] => -1 [32] => -20 [33] => 8 [34] => -17 [35] => -2 [36] => -6)
```

No non-integers.

Comment: Post the output from `print_r($diffarray);`

Comment: that was an abbreviation of the output, there are actually -0 values in the array. That is the problem.

Comment: I suspect `$diffarray` is a multi-dimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$diffarray[] = intval($roundedans);
```

As round() always returns float, the type wouldn't change if you multiply it with 10.

intval() will change the type.